# Wait for a thread that you can't reference

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using a method  `void Read(string speech)`, it plays the string speech
but when I call `Read()` 3 times, you can only hear the last string, Read doesn't wait for the previous calls to finish, that's what I want to do.

I dont have access to Read implementation because its a tts library method, but um pretty sure that it creates a new Thread and use it to play the sound (string given as parameter), i know there are several ways to wait for a thread to finish, like thread1.Join(); 
but to use those solutions i need to know the name of the thread or have a way to reference that Thread, since Read creates the Thread that i need to wait, my question is, how can i get that Threads name ??

Comment: Is this the windows text-to-speech or something else?  Code samples, library call details etc will help us to help you.

Comment: What library does Read come from? Maybe it has another method you can call to check the status, or force a wait.

Comment: Is there a ReadAsync or similar method available?

Comment: You can get the thread list before and after the read and find the new thread.

Comment: You really should provide more information with the question.

Comment: µBio, GolezTrol: its the Read from Loquendo 7 Text-to-speech,

Jeremy McGee: yes, but its for C,  almost all the examples from  Loquendo API  are in C, the c++ and C# says "coming soon", or "ignore this section, its under construction", and i cant find how to achieve a ReadAsync in C#

Comment: @Dani highly not recommended. What if some other thread puts a new thread in between your calls? How will you know which is which?

Comment: Write an event handler for the EndOfSpeech event

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) class?  It provides both synchronous and asynchronous Speak methods.  If using the synchronous method ([Speak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586901.aspx)), the speech will have completed before the method returns control to you.

Comment: Im using the Read from Loquendo,like this,  this._voice.Read(speech);
_voice declaration as follows,  private LTTS7Class _voice = new LTTS7Class();
and the library is,  LTTS7Lib;
regarding the asynchronous, yes, the library provides a way to do async but in C, for C# it does not provide the same options